# Unable to locate android sdk Flutter Mac

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am a new user to flutter and i installed android studio and flutter plug in. While running my flutter doctor -v it shows. I don't know how to fix it. help me out. I tried a lot to fix it but nothing helps me

```
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Users/apple/Developer/flutter/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /Users/apple/Developer/flutter/Contents
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Project Structure and solve some errors.

Android Studio -> File -> Project Structure.

Please check that you install dart and flutter plugin in the android studio.

Please install Dart in your system also.

Answer (score 0):

is there local.properties file present in your project, inside android folder ?

[image]

if not , then create a local.properties file and put your android sdk path inside it, like in my case

```
sdk.dir=/Users/tusharpandey/Library/Android/sdk
```